# Windows 7 - Eclipse: Why my keyboard is not working for typing a single " " "?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

When I try to define a String in Eclipse, when I type the **" '** button, is not working. When I pressed second time the button, it inserts two  **"**. Solutions?

I want the normal behavior! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your keyboard layout to something like [US International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#US-International)? This sounds pretty much like dead-key behavior for the `"` key.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Johannes Rössel's answer: here's how to do the swap (assuming you are using a US keyboard and English language version of Windows)

1. Click the Start button and type "keyboard language". Select "Change keyboards or other input methods".
2. A "Region and Language" window will appear with the "Keyboards and Languages" tab selected.  Click on the "Change keyboards..." button.
3. The "Text Services and Input Languages" window will appear.  On the "General" tab, in the "Installed services" section, look for "English (United States) -> Keyboard -> US". If it is there, skip ahead to step number 7
4. Click the "Add..." button.  The "Add Input Language" window will appear.
5. Expand the "English (United States)" tree and the "Keyboard" sub-tree under it.
6. Put a check mark next to the "US" option, then click "OK".  Return to the "Text Services and Input Languages" window.
7. In the "Default input language" section, click the drop-down menu and select, "English (United States) - US".
8. In the "Installed services" section, click "United States-International" if it is listed, then click the "Remove" button.  Repeat this for any other keyboards listed until only the "US" keyboard is listed.
9. Click the OK button.  Return to the "Region and Language" window, then click the OK button.

**Some programs will not notice this change until you reboot your computer.

P.S. to anybody who wants to up-vote this solution:  Please consider up-voting Johannes' answer as well.  I had this same issue once, and I would not have remembered this if it wasn't for Johannes' answer.